# Select randomly 3 rows equal number of times

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating an advertisement platform for my website, where we need select 3 rows randomly and number of times of banner display also should be balanced.

We can get the random rows like this,

`SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3`

and we can balance the number of times by incrementing count field while selecting the row each time and select the rows with less count like this,

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY display_count LIMIT 0,3`.

But it will return the values like `1,2,3`,`4,5,6` and so. But i need to select rows with minimum count randomly. Any suggestion or idea on this would be great?

Comment: Can you post some sample data with expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY display_count ASC, RAND() 
LIMIT 0,3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND(), display_count LIMIT 0,3
```

?
I think this is what you want.

Comment: I've tested and worked ok. Can you tell me why is not working?